# The import com.example cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, import, protocol-buffers, importerror

I am trying to compile this example given by Google on the protocol buffers:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial

It comes with a ListPeople.java and AddPerson.java file along with a bunch of imports. The problem is that i am getting "The import com.example cannot be resolved" as seen in this screenshot:

```
http://postimg.org/image/67whg6a57/full/

This is the full path of the import com.example java file:
http://postimg.org/image/wexoc4sez/full/

and where all of my files are located:
http://postimg.org/image/4veseacpn/full/
```

I've tried to do the following:

```
Project->Clean
File->Refresh
Property->Java build path->add external JAR:
http://postimg.org/image/xjrqhievv/full/
```

None of these has work. What is the problem?

Comment: did u try a clean ?? Also go to build path, order and import besides the add jar tab and check is all the external files are checked

Comment: Yes clean was one of the things i tried as listed above(unless you mean something else). I tried selecting them all but it did not change anything. Jon Skeet said "you dont want to have source files as libraries" so isn't that contradicting what he is saying?

Comment: well indeed, u could obviously import another package as a library bt u dont need to export them as external files the way its shown in the image :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this seems to be code that is missing from your project.  If you press `Shift-Ctrl-T` and type in AddressBook, is it there?

If it is not there then it has not been generated from the example .proto files as specifiied in the `Google on the protocol buffers` files

Comment: So that means that either the source itself, of the jars are missing from your project.  Donwload then and add them

Comment: Not sure i follow, the example did not come with a .jar, only folders with already .java files

Comment: The files are generated from the .proto files in the project

Comment: correct, the protoc is a compiler that generates a .java file called AddressBook which is what i am trying to import. Should i recompile the file?

Comment: right, so add the directory to your eclipse project as a source folder in the build path settings

Comment: Okay i fixed that but now i am getting problems from the actual AddressBook .java file with its own import of com.google.protobuf.
for example com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistry. I have them all located in C:\Users\Home\Desktop\hi\src\com\google\protobuf but i get com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistry cannot be resolved to a type. I changed the location of my project by the way. I recreated everything and it is now in C:\Users\Home\Desktop\hi\src\

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39981/discussion-between-user2644819-and-user2310289)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add Java *source* files as if they're libraries - they're not.

Add the "src" directory as a Source Path (leftmost tab in the Java Build Path settings) instead. Or if that's already a source path, try refreshing it in package explorer. Either way, you definitely don't want to have source files as libraries...

Comment: It said it was already a source path. Where is the package explorer setting?

Comment: @user2644819: No, you didn't say that. Your question doesn't use the word "source" at all, and you've shown a screenshot of you trying to use the source files as *libraries*.